# Fire cached Http request in angular 4

Tags: angular, http, caching

I have a cached http request.I have done following:

1. Used interceptor.
2. Clone http request.
3. stored cloned http request

Now I would like to fire this cached request. How can I ?

Any Help will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you please share code which you are using to clone http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my query asked above.
we can use 'request' function of HttpClient library. example:

fireRequest(request) {

return **this.http.request**(cached);

}